# Cannot assign io.reactivex.Flowable <io.reactivex.Maybe> to: io.reactivex.Flowable <Object>

Tags: java, groovy, reactive-programming, flatmap

Hope You're all doing will. I'm very new to this and I keep getting issues with incompatible types.

```
Flowable<Boolean> checkTriggerDaily() {

        List<Bson> fields = new ArrayList<Bson>();
        fields.add(exists("dueDate", true));
        Bson filter = and(fields);

        Flowable.fromPublisher(marketplaceMongoService.getCollection().find(filter)).map{ third ->
                    getTheReport(third.id).flatMap { size ->
                     TaskService.createTasks(size).toFlowable().flatMap({})
                    }
                }
    }
```

I keep getting the same error on the title. What this function does is loop through a mongo collection and call getTheReport every item. What the getTheReportReturns, i process it to createTasks function.

getTheReport -> returns Maybe
createTasks -> returns Maybe

Comment: where is the return statement in your method?

Comment: It is `groovy` code, so the last expression would be the method result.

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
getTheReport(third.id).flatMap { size ->
    TaskService.createTasks(size).toFlowable().flatMap({})
}
```

result is a `Flowalbe`, you should call `flatMap` instead of `map` so that the internal function emitted objects get unpacked into a *flat* result:

```
Flowable<Boolean> checkTriggerDaily() {

    List<Bson> fields = new ArrayList<Bson>();
    fields.add(exists("dueDate", true));
    Bson filter = and (fields);

    Flowable.fromPublisher(marketplaceMongoService.getCollection().find(filter))
        .flatMap { third -> // flatMap instead of map
            getTheReport(third.id).flatMap { size ->
                TaskService.createTasks(size).toFlowable().flatMap({})
            }
        }
}
```